# Change Tag InnerText with HTML AGILITY PACK

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Im using HTML Agility Pack, and Im trying to replace the InnerText of some Tags like this

```
protected void GerarHtml()
{
    List<string> labels = new List<string>();

    string patch = @"C:\EmailsMKT\" + 
                              Convert.ToString(Session["ssnFileName"]) + ".html";

     DocHtml.Load(patch);

     //var titulos = DocHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='lblmkt']");

     foreach (HtmlNode titulo in
              DocHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='lblmkt']"))
     {
          titulo.InnerText.Replace("test", lbltitulo1.Text);
     }

     DocHtml.Save(patch);

}
```

the html:

```
<.div><.label id="titulo1" class="lblmkt">teste</label.><./Div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable (you should be able to find much documentation on this).
Methods of the String class do not alter the instance, but rather create a new, modified string.

Thus, your call to:

```
titulo.InnerText.Replace("test", lbltitulo1.Text);
```

does not alter InnerText, but returns the string you want InnerText to be.

In addition, InnerText is read-only; you'll have to use Text as shown in [Set InnerText with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838282/set-innertext-with-html-agility-pack)

Try the following line instead (assign the result of the string operation to the property again):

```
titulo.Text = titulo.Text.Replace("test", lbltitulo1.Text);
```

Comment: I tryed, but i received HtmlAgilityPack.InnerText it is Ready Only

Answer (score 1):

I was able get the result like this:

```
HtmlTextNode Hnode = null;
Hnode = DocHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@id='titulo1']//text()") as HtmlTextNode;
Hnode.Text = lbltitulo1.Text;
```

Comment: : 'Unable to cast object of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode'.'